# Is there any way to set skip expression of task using java code in flowable or any dynamic way to set skip expression of task

Tags: flowable

I have checked in flowable rest API but I have not found any rest call which can I use to set skip expression of the task.

I have also checked in the API documentation of flowable but unable to find a way to set skip expression dynamically using java code.

If any have any idea how can we set skip expression of flowable task dynamically using java code or any other dynamic way without setting skip expression for the flowable modeler.

The flowable version is: 6.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the `flowable:skipExpression` from the BPMN XML to be used the process instance needs to have a variable named `_FLOWABLE_SKIP_EXPRESSION_ENABLED` with the value of `true`

Comment: I set like this execution.setVariable("_FLOWABLE_SKIP_EXPRESSION_ENABLED", true); but still not working. Am I missing something ?